# How and where filter and sort query results using symfony 2.4 ( according to MCV )

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, twig

I am pretty sure there has to be a clean and nice way to do this.
I need to offer the user the option to see all the rows of a table in a page (maybe pagination here would be awesome too) and then allow him to filter for those which has some value in some specific field. Also it would be great to allow re order this results.

Because I don't know from ahead which filter or sorting will apply I simply give all the set of data to my twig template which in turn print all those. Until here everything  ok.
But this is the point where I dont know how to proceed...

So suppose you have:

ControllerDefault.php

```
...default header....

public function listAction()
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $entities = $em->getRepository('ACMEAppBundle:Item')->findAll();
    return $this->render('ACMEAppBundle:Default:list.html.twig', array('entities'=>$entities));
}
```

list.html.twig

```
{% extends '::base.html.twig' %}
{% block content %}
<h3>List of items</h3>

<table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>id</th>
        <th>name</th>
        <th>details</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    {% for entity in entities %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ entity.id }}</td>
            <td>{{ entity.name }}</td>
            <td>{{ entity.details }}</td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

{% endblock %}

Would you use a text with a button for action and then trying to generate a new url by sending some kind of variable back to the controller? or maybe generating a url for a different action?

Would you prefer AJAX somehow on this page...if so? how would be the most basic implementation?

Any advise will be much appreciated since this is for real work and my endline is two days ahead (how I ended doing this is another story xD)

Thanks!!!

Comment: What do you mean by "has some value in some specific field"?

Comment: If you need to show ordered list, the most basic implementation is using get parameters like 'order', 'direction' and so on.

Ajax is better because you don't need to render the whole page - just send a small text messages to the server. Take a look at Angular - it might be more helpful in this case then pure js with ajax calls.

Comment: Thanks Alex. I was talking about some filter criteria... i.e. some text field equals  or include some text value given

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need this: [KnpPaginatorBundle](https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpPaginatorBundle)

1) Add this to Your composer.json file (/composer.json):

```
{
    "require": {
        "knplabs/knp-paginator-bundle": "~2.4"
    }
}
```

2) Type in Your console in root dir of Your project:

```
composer update knplabs/knp-paginator-bundle
```

If You don't have composer:
https://getcomposer.org/download/

3) Add this to Your config.yml (/app/config/config.yml):

```
knp_paginator:
    page_range: 5                      # default page range used in pagination control
    default_options:
        page_name: page                # page query parameter name
        sort_field_name: sort          # sort field query parameter name
        sort_direction_name: direction # sort direction query parameter name
        distinct: true                 # ensure distinct results, useful when ORM queries are using GROUP BY statements
    template:
        pagination: KnpPaginatorBundle:Pagination:sliding.html.twig     # sliding pagination controls template
        sortable: KnpPaginatorBundle:Pagination:sortable_link.html.twig # sort link template
```

4) Register bundle in AppKernel.php (/app/AppKernel.php):

```
public function registerBundles()
{
    return array(
        // ...
        new Knp\Bundle\PaginatorBundle\KnpPaginatorBundle(),
        // ...
    );
}
```

5) Now replace the listAction (ControllerDefault.php):

```
public function listAction()
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $dql   = "SELECT i FROM ACMEAppBundle:Item i";
    $query = $em->createQuery($dql);
    $paginator  = $this->get('knp_paginator');
    $entities = $paginator->paginate(
        $query,
        $this->get('request')->query->get('page', 1)/*page number*/,
        10/*limit per page*/
    );

    return $this->render('ACMEAppBundle:Default:list.html.twig', array('entities'=>$entities));
}
```

6) At last Your must change the view (list.html.twig):

```
{% extends '::base.html.twig' %}
{% block content %}
<h3>List of items ({{ entities.getTotalItemCount }})</h3>

<table>
    <thead>
    <tr> {# sorting of properties based on query components #}
        <th>{{ knp_pagination_sortable(entities , 'Id', 'i.id') }}</th>
        <th>{{ knp_pagination_sortable(entities , 'Name', 'i.name') }}</th>
        <th>{{ knp_pagination_sortable(entities , 'Details ', 'i.details ') }}</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    {% for entity in entities %}
        <tr>

            <td>{{ entity.id }}</td>
            <td>{{ entity.name }}</td>
            <td>{{ entity.details }}</td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>

{# display navigation #}
<div class="pagination">
    {{ knp_pagination_render(entities) }}
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Pawel, great info there! 
But before closing this issue! Would you mind explaining me how is it possible to implement some filtering on those listings?. For example suppose you have a field "customer" on those items. How can I offer a way to filter by items with some specific customer? Maybe nice with a text input or a selec previously loaded with all the customers available.

Comment: This sorting based on DQL queries, so you can only determine the direction of sorting (DESC / ASC) and the field in eg. customer. This sorting as you describe requires a WHERE clause. Its possible,
You would have to select with customers and send choosed customer ID in the URL, then the controller receive this ID in eg. `$this->get('request')->get('customer_id')` .
After if You get customer Id add it to query by ->addWhere() method. http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html

Comment: yeah my friend. Sorry for forgetting accepting the answer... I was hoping to get some more info on filtering results... but at the end I realized that I needed to program it for myself... using some jquery with a couple of <select> (using FOSJsRoutingBundle and exposign the route) and including the filtering parameters on my route so it can reload already filtered from the controller. 
Thanks again! the pagination method is great man ;)